# Retrieving over-encoded information in csv file?

Tags: python, csv, encoding

I have been logging thousands of messages for a data science project into a csv file. Many of these messages contain either emojis or non-English characters, therefore when opening the csv file using Excel, these already appeared in an encoded format (e.g. the red heart emoji `❤️` got encoded as `â¤ï¸`). This didn't disturb me much in the beginning, as I only needed the csv to store my data that I periodically analyzed. When reading the csv file using Python, I didn't notice any data corruption.

(However, I made an apparently huge mistake a couple of days ago: I ran into an error when reading the csv file, so I specified the `engine` attribute of `pd.read_csv` as `'python'` and I believe this launched it all: every time I re-ran the script that updates the csv, all the text data got encoded again, possibly in `utf-8` instead of csv's orriginal `windows-1252`.) **Edit:** *I realized thank to Tomalak's comments below that the real problem wasn't this modification but me manually modifying the csv file using Excel a number of times along the way.*

The older the csv entries, the more the subsequent encoding-recoding affected them: for the newest entries, there is no issue but for the oldest ones, I now have a single heart emoji appearing in the csv as:

- `ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¯Ã‚Â¿Ã‚Â½Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¤ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¯Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¸ÃƒÂ¯Ã‚Â¿Ã‚Â½ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¯Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¸ÃƒÂ¯Ã‚Â¿Ã‚Â½`

I found numerous entries in the csv file where I could easily apply the `.encode('windows-1252').decode('utf-8')` 3-6 times (depending on how old the given entry is and therefore how many times it got re-encoded) and obtained a favorable outcome, such as:

- `ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â°Ãƒâ€¦Ã‚Â¸Ãƒâ€¹Ã…â€œÃƒâ€¦Ã‚Â¾` stands for the sad/disappointed face emoji (). Applying the encoding-decoding pattern four times returned: `\U0001f61e` which is good enough for me; I can easily use `unicodedata` library's excellent conversion method to obtain their corresponding `unicodedata.name`. I believe that's how I should be storing emojis from now on...

My understanding about applying the above mentioned encode-decode pattern numerous times is that I cannot overdo it. If one string needs only three of these patterns while the next cell needs six, I could just do something like this (yes, I know `iterrows()` is a terribly inefficient approach but just for the example):

```
for idx, _ in df.iterrows():
    tmp = df.loc[idx, 'text']
    for _ in range(6):
        tmp = tmp.encode("windows-1252").decode("utf-8")
    df.loc[idx, 'text'] = tmp
```

The problem is, however, that there are still quite a lot of entries where the above solution doesn't work. Let's just consider the above mentioned encoded string which stands for a red heart:

- `ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¯Ã‚Â¿Ã‚Â½Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¤ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¯Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¸ÃƒÂ¯Ã‚Â¿Ã‚Â½ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¯Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¸ÃƒÂ¯Ã‚Â¿Ã‚Â½`

Applying `.encode("windows-1252").decode("utf-8")` three times yields: `â�¤ï¸�ï¸�` but when attempting to apply the pattern the fourth time, I get: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufffd' in position 1: character maps to <undefined>`. My hunch is, not all strings were encoded by `windows-1252`...?

Is there any hope to get back my data in an uncorrupted format?

Comment: *"e.g. the red heart emoji ❤️ got encoded as â¤ï¸"* - no, nothing "got encoded" by Excel. You have saved your CSV file in UTF-8, but you've not opened it as UTF-8 in Excel, but as Windows-1252. You need to pick the right encoding when opening a text file in Excel (and Python, and *any* other tool that deals with text files). Not explicitly picking a file encoding always is a bug.

Comment: I never said it got encoded by Excel though... :)

Comment: "When I opened the file in Excel, it got encoded".

Comment: Alright, so most likely the mistake wasn't with Python but me modifying the csv file manually along the way. It's a good tip to always add the attribute `encoding='utf-8'` to `pd.read_csv` and `df.to_csv`. But when I apply that now, I still have the corrupted entries, e.g. `ÃƒÂ¢Ã¯Â¿Â½Ã‚Â¤` instead of `❤️`.

Comment: But your hunch is right, not all strings were alternatingly encoded as either `Windows-1252` or `UTF-8`. There is a considerable chance that your data got mangled irreversibly at some point along the way.

Comment: See [ftfy](https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which can be used for fixing mojibake.